# Undesired space between two different divs?

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I think I know why this is happening. As you'll see, I have placed my text boxes with background images on top of those other images via `bottom`. Is that bad practice? Is there a more efficient way to do it? The problem is that I need a transparent image so that you can still kind of see the picture when you hover over it and I couldn't figure out how to do that via two background images.

It works to some extent, but I think the fact that it may be bad practice comes back to bite me in the butt when the second row of images you'll see are unable to inhabit the space that the text boxes inhabited before `bottom` moved them. I thought that by placing them all in one `div` (`rowTwo`) I would be able to move them all as a singular unit. But they seem to refuse to move at all and aren't even contained within the `div` in the layout which you can see from the dotted line box which is where I would like the row to be.

Maybe this was all more than one question... And I'm sorry for that. But if someone could help to educate me that would be fantastic! Thank you so much. Here is the JSFiddle (sorry for those weird placeholder images):

```css
.rowOne {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 415px;
    width: 1050px;
}

.rowTwo {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 415px;
    width: 1050px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

.episodeText {
    background-image: url("fadeBox.png");
    width: 350px;
    height: 415px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 437px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.episodeText:hover {
    background-image: url("fadeBox.png");
    width: 350px;
    height: 415px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 437px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.episodeImage {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.episodeText a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
}



.episode h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.episode p1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 280px;
    height:200px;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: inherit
}

.episode {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "dontgoogleit2.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<a href="default.html">
<div class= logo>
<img src= "websitelogo.png">
</div>
</a>
<title>
pls dnt
</title>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
 <a href="episodes.html" id="episodes">EPISODES</a>
 <a href="sources.html" id="sources">SOURCES</a>
 <a href="about.html" id ="about">ABOUT</a>
 <a href="contactus.html" id ="contact">CONTACT US</a>
</div>
</head>
<body class=body>
<div class= "theEpisodes">
<div class="rowOne">
<div class="episode">
<div class= "episodeImage">
<img src="https://www.girlsgonestrong.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/longandlean-origin-and-insertion-example-350x415.png">
</div>
<div class= "episodeText">
<a href= "#sound">
<h1>
Episode 1: A Dental Disturbance
</h1>
<p1>
The first episode, and what better way to start than with a lovely little tool we use to start our day. Yes, that's right
the toothbrush. Where did it come from? Who invented it? Simple questions, unclear answers. There's a mystery afoot, and we're
going to point it out. Come one, come all and witness the birth of the most beloved and most hated of devices.
</p1>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="episode">
<div class= "episodeImage">
<img src="https://www.girlsgonestrong.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/longandlean-origin-and-insertion-example-350x415.png">
</div>
<div class= "episodeText">
<a href= "#sound">
<h1>
Episode 2: A Dental Disturbance (Part II)
</h1>
<p1>
Ah yes, the exciting conclusion of our two-part series on toothbrushes. Are you on the edge of your seats?
Because a certain Saudi Arabian dentist has emailed a certain podcaster back. Yes, that's right. Hold on to
your miswaks. Plus, a dutiful dive into the murky depths of unclean mouths and minds, further investigations
into the first patented toothbrush, as well as other designs of the future and past.
</p1>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="episode">
<div class= "episodeImage">
<img src="https://www.girlsgonestrong.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/longandlean-origin-and-insertion-example-350x415.png">
</div>
<div class= "episodeText">
<a href= "#sound">
<h1>
Episode 3: Nice to Meet Screw
</h1>
<p1>
Screws. So many screws. Who invented the screw? Why all of these beautiful shapes and where did they
come from? Which one's the best? All of these questions will be answered, kind of. Join us as we embark
on a journey through time. From the time of Ancient Greek mathematicians, Babylonian kings to a poor man
ahead of his time, a happy-go-lucky Canadian and crafty manufacturers.
</p1>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="rowTwo">
<div class="episode">
<div class= "episodeImage">
<img src="https://www.girlsgonestrong.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/longandlean-origin-and-insertion-example-350x415.png">
</div>
<div class= "episodeText">
<a href= "#sound">
<h1>
Episode 4: Gothip Guys
</h1>
<p1>
Two normies discuss the roots and implications of goth culture. From the ancient tribes of Europe to the Bat Cave, we delve shallowly into a deeply misunderstood subculture. Who are the goths? What do they want? Where did they come from? Music. Literature. Art. Architecture. Don't Google It.
</p1>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="episode">
<div class= "episodeImage">
<img src="https://www.girlsgonestrong.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/longandlean-origin-and-insertion-example-350x415.png">
</div>
<div class= "episodeText">
<a href= "#sound">
<h1>
Episode 5: IP-YAY
</h1>
<p1>
Things get a little out of hand as two very refined gentleman discuss the ins and outs of the beer industry--specifically craft beers and IPAs. Hear the confusing (and somewhat false) tale about where the IPA comes from. We also muse upon the definitions of the terms "craft beers" and "IPA"s. What does it all mean? What is it all pointing to? One thing is for sure, you shouldn't google it.
</p1>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="episode">
<div class= "episodeImage">
<img src="https://www.girlsgonestrong.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/longandlean-origin-and-insertion-example-350x415.png">
</div>
<div class= "episodeText">
<a href= "#sound">
<h1>
Episode 6: Real Men Talk Pink
</h1>
<p1>
Pink. It's not just for girls anymore. But why was it ever a color "for girls"? How long had it been that way? Well, we'll do our best to answer all of your questions and also bloviate endlessly about our fragile male egos. From the early conception of pink, to the feminist movements, to the "Real Men Wear Pink" movement, we'll try our best to conquer the ever-shifting pink landscape.
</p1>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is too large please create a working fiddle link

Comment: @Lokesh You should be able to click "Run code snippet" and it will run like a fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add height to the episode style to match the episodeText height, that blank space collapses, which I think is what you want:

```
episode {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 415px;
}
```

Comment: Oh Stephen R. Smith, you've made me the happiest man alive. EDIT: So just to be clear so that I don't repeat this mistake again... by changing the height of the episode to that of the episodeText, the episodeText conforms to the same space as episode rather than taking up it's own space? Did that make sense?

Comment: My pleasure - glad I could help!